# nested foreach loop, 1st loop not looping

Tags: php

Im trying to get my array to loop in the foreach loop but it keeps looping the same one over and over. What am I doing wrong?

```
$classes = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black', 'purple', 'grey');
foreach($classes as $class){
foreach ($html->find('.yfnc_datamodoutline1 .yfnc_tabledata1') as $element){
    $symbols = $element->outertext;
    echo '<div class="'.$class.'">'.$symbols.'</div>';
}
```

it outputs this

```
<div class="red">Jul 6, 2012</div>
<div class="red">12,889.40</div>
<div class="red">12,889.40</div>
<div class="red">12,702.99</div>
<div class="red">12,772.47</div>
<div class="red">967,600</div>
<div class="red">12,772.47</div>
```

Im trying to make it output this

```
<div class="red">Jul 6, 2012</div>
<div class="blue">12,889.40</div>
<div class="yellow">12,889.40</div>
<div class="green">12,702.99</div>
<div class="black">12,772.47</div>
<div class="purple">967,600</div>
<div class="grey">12,772.47</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use nested loops for this, instead use an index in the color array.

```
$classes = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black', 'purple', 'grey');
$ci = 0;
foreach ($html->find('.yfnc_datamodoutline1 .yfnc_tabledata1') as $element){
    $symbols = $element->outertext;
    echo '<div class="'.$classes[$ci].'">'.$symbols.'</div>';
    $ci++;
    if($ci == count($classes)) $ci = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it, I couldnt understand why it wasnt working since it was in a foreach loop.